# Blackberry: Read a text file packaged in the project (faster)

Tags: java, blackberry, input

I've tried this approach:

http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800620/How_To_-_Add_plain_text_or_binary_files_to_an_application.html?nodeid=800687&vernum=0

But it's REALLY slow for slightly large text files. Does anyone know of a better way of reading a plain text file that is included in the project? Is there a way to use FileConnection?

Comment: That is a VERY bad code example - it reads from the input stream one byte at a time - no wonder it's so slow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out using a combination of information:

> IOUtilities.streamToBytes(is);

Directly on the input stream. So a more complete example would be as follows:

> Class classs = Class.forName("com.packagename.stuff.FileDemo");
>
> InputStream is = classs.getResourceAsStream("/test");
>
> byte[] data = IOUtilities.streamToBytes(is);
>
> String result = new String(data);

Deal? Deal.