# "File system error (1003)" opening BlackBerry file connection

Tags: file, blackberry, java-me, resources

I tried the example from ["J2ME/Blackberry - how to read/write text file?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519328/j2me-blackberry-how-to-read-write-text-file). I want only the read functionality, the file I want to read is in CSV format as a .txt file placed in the /res/test.txt.

But I am having an issue with the FileConnection. I get the following error:

> File system error (1003)

Any suggestions or advice on a better approach or as to how I can get this working?

```
public class FileDemo extends MainScreen {

public FileDemo() {
    setTitle("My Page");
    String str = readTextFile("file:///test.txt");
    System.out.println("Contents of the file::::::: " + str);
}

public String readTextFile(String fName) {
    String result = null;
    FileConnection fconn = null;
    DataInputStream is = null;
    try {
        fconn = (FileConnection) Connector.openInputStream(fName);
        is = fconn.openDataInputStream();
        byte[] data = IOUtilities.streamToBytes(is);
        result = new String(data);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {
            if (null != is)
                is.close();
            if (null != fconn)
                fconn.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    return result;
}
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267881/blackberry-read-a-text-file-packaged-in-the-project-faster
refer this link.

Comment: tried the above link.. dint work for me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/test.txt");
StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
int ch;
try {
    while ((ch = is.read()) != -1)
    buff.append((char) ch);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.Error(e, "Exception ");
}
String str = (buff.toString());
```

Comment: Answers on SO should be more than just an answer - explanation matters too.  Can you explain where Vikas went wrong in his code, and what specifically about your code snippet fixes it?

Answer (score 0):

Same problem I also faced in my project. First check your simulator memory card is inserted or not. From simulator,

go to **Options(Settings)-->Device-->Storage** and Check the Memory card Storage.

If the memory card is not inserted, than it will show **Media Card is not currently inserted** in the device. So, you need to insert the memory card. From simulator menu bar, choose **simulate-->Change SD Card...**
You can add the SD card here. Than you try.

I think, This suggestion will help someone.